# It's some kind of magic... or bug?

Tags: windows, delphi

I added my program to the SendTo. I send two files to it.
They are:

```
C:\ThisIsMySuperTestHelloWorld\ThisBookIsRedMyPenIsWhite\test.jpg
C:\ThisIsMySuperTestHelloWorld\ThisBookIsRedMyPenIsWhite\hello.jpg
```

The code below shows `C:\ThisIsMySuperTestHelloWorld\ThisBookIsRedMyPenIsWhite\test.jpg@C:\ThisIsMySuperTestHelloWorld\ThisBookIsRedMyPenIsWhite\test.jpg`

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var Files: array of PAnsiChar;
    i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Files, 2);

  for i:=0 to 1 do begin
   Files[i] := PAnsiChar(ParamStr(2+i));
  end;

  ShowMessage( Files[0] +'@' + Files[1] );
end;
```

I use Delphi 6 on Windows7.
Under Delphi Xe3 (still Win7) I changed (both) PAnsiChar to PWideChar and I have the same effect.

My SendTo link links to:

```
"C:\<PATH_HERE>\Project1.exe" c
```

and is placed here:

```
C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
```

Comment: You can add even more magic by using `PChar` instead of `PAnsiChar`/`PWideChar` and now it does not matter if you compile with Delphi 6 or Delphi XE3

Comment: When it comes to programming, there's no such thing as magic. That's actually the problem these days - too many people think there's some sort of voodoo behind software.

Comment: Please, read [this article about using PChar and strings](http://praxis-velthuis.de/rdc/articles/articles-pchars.html). Using PChars here is not a good idea, as others already noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using strings? For example:

```
procedure HandleParams;
var Files: array of string;
    i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Files, ParamCount);
  for i := 1 to ParamCount do
        Files[i-1] := ParamStr(i);

  if ParamCount >= 2 then
        ShowMessage( Files[0] +'@' + Files[1] );
end;
```

Your code does not work, because PAnsiChar is only a Pointer and does not store the actual string data. When you assign the string returned from the ParamStr function only a pointer to the (temporary) function result is stored. The actual data is overwritten with the next function call. This can even crash your program when further used.

By the way, your ParamStr index iterates over 2 and 3, with references to the second and third parameter; maybe that's not intended as the arguments start at index 1 (index 0 being the program call itself)?

To solve the issue one has to store the string data, which makes the pointers kinda useless, but anyway, here's a fixed version of your example:

```
procedure HandleParamsPAnsi;
var Files: array of PAnsiChar;
    FilesData: array of AnsiString;
    i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Files, 2);
  SetLength(FilesData, 2);

  for i:=0 to 1 do begin
      FilesData[i] := AnsiString(ParamStr(1+i));
      Files[i] := PAnsiChar(FilesData[i]);
  end;

  ShowMessage( Files[0] + '@' + Files[1] );
end;
```

Comment: I would just use a `TStringList` instead. Loop through `ParamCount()` storing each `ParamStr()` value in the list, and then set its `Delimiter` property to `@` and read its `DelimitedText` property.

Comment: *... your ParamStr index iterates over 2 and 3, ...*  Maybe you did not notice that there already is one argument, `c` in the SendTo link

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know PChars are just Pointers since I can do: `var C: PChar; begin C := 'Hello World';` and the memory gets allocated. You clarified things out for me. Thanks again!